# How to access project (opened project) appsetting or any config file from Visual studio extension Project(VSIX)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, visual-studio-2022

Is there any code and method to access project appsetting.json/web config or any file when running Visual studio Extention project (VSIS project).

I want to get the connection string from the open project when executing a command from VSIX project. the command may be menu click or solution explorer custom add menu click.
Thanks in advance.